# USB HID driver data sniffing

Tags: drivers, usb, hid

I need to communicate with a proprietary HID device. I don't have a driver for it, nor documentation on its communication. I did however obtain some compiled code that configures the HID device and retrieves data from it.

I'd like to sniff the communication between the compiled code and the HID device to replicate it, and to retrieve data in python.

What are the possible strategies to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. If you are using Linux, just to sniff into, you can use the command `strace` to know how the device is being accessed. In my case was by ioctl's calls as described in `/usr/include/Linux/hiddev.h`. From that, you can hook the ioctl calls and inspect all exchanged messages. There are a good example at [ldpreload](https://github.com/poliva/ldpreloadhook.git), but will need to change it to dump HID's messages.

Good luck, it is not an easy task.